# How to create a Windows task to synchronize files over Google Drive just once a week?

Tags: windows, sync, task-scheduler

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and using Google Drive to backup only the unimportant data. I want them to sync just once a week to not to waste computer and network resources all the time (checking for new content, uploading temporary files).

I would like to create a Windows Task Scheduler task, that starts Google Drive once a week and after 1 hour of running - when all files should be synchronized - it should end automatically.

The first part is easy, with the help: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html

I've created a new task, that starts:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"
```

Then in task settings I checked:

```
Stop the task if it runs longer than: 1 hour
+
If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop
```

According to the task history, the task itself terminates after 1 hour of running, but GoogleDrive application is still running in the background.

How can I also kill the GoogleDrive application when the task terminates?

Comment: I've looked in the Windows Services and there is no one that has anything to do with Google Drive. Little googling showed, that there is no Google Drive service at default (but can be created using: http://www.myrtec.com.au/kb/331)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use google drive, but I would add another scheduled task at the hour's end.

Can just make a batch file if you want.

"taskkill /f /im nameofexecutable.exe"

Run that minus the " " and that will force close the program.

Comment: What if the first scheduled task start is delayed? Is it possible to start the second task after the first is terminated?